# Camel error handler processor exception not caught

Tags: apache-camel

Hei,

I try to setup a camel route like this:

```
        onException(UnrecoverableException.class)
           .process(new UnrecoverableExceptionProcessor());

        onException(MappingException.class)
           .process(new MappingExceptionProcessor())
           .to(undeliverableChannel);
```

In case a MappingException is thrown the MappingExceptionProcessor is called.
This processor itself can throw an exception (for example UnrecoverableException). I am not able to catch this exception throw by the processor. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell. What happens after the processor throws the exception?

Comment: You cannot have an onException which throws an exception cause anothre onException to trigger, eg this could lead to endless behavior, therefore Camel does not allow that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Right, I can not have an onException to throw another Exception. Is there any recommended way to handle this use case? Can I use the exchange headers to add additional routing information for further processors?